# Add object to php array in symfony

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, object

I currently have 2 classes:

1. workerListClass
2. workerClass

The workerListClass gets a list of work with ids from database. For each of these the workerClass is called

```
foreach ($query as $value) {
        $result = $this->worker->getWorkerById($value['ID']); // DB Call to get additional data
        $this->addData($result);

        vardumper::dump($result->getId());
        // This results in 1031 and 1528
    }
```

addDate is very simple

```
public function addData(workerClass $worker): void
{
    $this->data[] = $worker;
}
```

But if i try to go through this array something strange happens

```
        $result = $this->workerListClass->getWorker()->getData();
    foreach ($result as $worker) {
        vardumper::dump([
            $worker->getId() // this outputs 1528 twice!!!
        ]);
    }
```

getData does nothing special

```
public function getData(): array
{
    return $this->data;
}
```

Can someone help me why this outputs 1528 twice?

Comment: well, try outputting `$this->data` before changing it.  Maybe it's in there already, maybe you call this 2x.  Who knows.  if you do `print_r($this->data)` in `addData` and it outputs 2x then your calling it 2x.  If it outputs once with that stuff in there, then that stuff was already in there etc...

Comment: Could it be that you save the worker as reference in the array? ( Return reference to object from `getWorkerById()`)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix there is no duplicate call, its just those things as stated. print_r shows that the first round is added correctly, after adding the second one the first one is overwritten, altthough not stated in the code.

Comment: @dWinder getWorkerById has a "return $this" with the workerClass Type.

Comment: `after adding the second one the first one is overwritten` - not with this `$this->data[]` its not.  That is like calling `array_push` it just appends a new item.  Something like `$this->data[$worker->getId()] = $worker;` would overwrite it.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Yeah i know, thats why this is strange... But its happening. I still get this output: array:1 [
  0 => "201903220859151528"
]
array:1 [
  0 => "201903220859151528"
]

Answer (score 0):

Problem found. The issues was that the same class was changed and not a new class was setup.

Using clone on the workerlist helped fixing this:

```
foreach ($query as $value) {
        $localWorker = clone $this->worker; //starts a new instance so that it is not referenced
        $result = $localWorker->getWorkerById($value['ID']);
        $this->addData($result);
        vardumper::dump($result->getId());
    }
```